# Common origin in matplotlib figures

Tags: matplotlib

I am constructing a 3D scatter plot using matplotlib, but cannot get the figure produced to have a common origin for all 3 axes. How can I do this?

My code (so far), i haven't implemented any definitions for the axes specifications because i'm very new to Python:

```
  from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


  # imports specific to the plots in this example
  import numpy as np
  from matplotlib import cm
  from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import get_test_data

  def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
  return (vmax-vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

  # Same as wide as it is tall.
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1.0))


  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

  n = 512

  xs = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=n)
  ys = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=n)
  zs = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=n)
  colors = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=n)
  scat = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=colors, marker='o')

  ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
  ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
  ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')


  fig.colorbar(scat, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)

  plt.show()
```

Comment: What have you tried, e.g. how do you set axes limits? Show some minimal code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'common origin'?  At first glance this code looks reasonable and mostly correct.

Comment: Thanks for your response tcaswell. By common origin, i mean where the axes all begin at the same point. When i run the above code, i get different origins, not coincident.

Comment: Ok, so you want to change the location of the coordinate axes. I couldn't find any hint of that either and it is either undocumented or not implemented (maybe on of `mplot3d`'s rough edges).

Comment: are you looking for `set_xlim` `set_ylim` and `set_zlim`?

Comment: Yes tcaswell, but I don't know if this will position the limits of all 3 axes at the same location. It is a very pedantic point, but my 3D plots will be easier to follow if the origin (0,0,0) is clearly defined.

Comment: You only have one axes.  Which is why I am still confused by your question.

Comment: In the plot there are 3 axes. It is a 3-dimensional plot. Anyway, these are sample values along each dimension, since my values will remain positive, perhaps the definition of the location of the origin will be less ambiguous.

Comment: There are 3 `axis` objects, but only one `axes`.  There is only one origin in your axes (0, 0, 0) where the origins of the three `axis` line up.

Comment: @tcaswell I think it's pretty clear the OP wants his visual axis lines to cross at (0,0,0) in the center of his plot. Regardless which mplot3d class represents what part of the resulting figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you mean something as follows (from Mathematica):

[image: Mathematica]

At the present time I can only plot some lines centered at (0,0,0):

```
xline=((min(data[:,0]),max(data[:,0])),(0,0),(0,0))
ax.plot(xline[0],xline[1],xline[2],'grey')
yline=((0,0),(min(data[:,1]),max(data[:,1])),(0,0))
ax.plot(yline[0],yline[1],yline[2],'grey')
zline=((0,0),(0,0),(min(data[:,2]),max(data[:,2])))
ax.plot(zline[0],zline[1],zline[2],'grey')
```

This is the result:

[image: Matplotlib]

Answer (score 0):

If you put the line

```
ax.view_init(30,220)
```

just before

```
plt.show()
```

you should get what you want for x-y plane. No idea about how to move that plane to z=0.